# Sending an emal from gmail in python 3

Tags: email, python-3.x

I'm doing my first project and was reading in my textbook and wrote this program,

```
import smtplib
password=input(str("Enter your password for example@gmail.com")
smtp0bj.ehlo()
smtp0bj.starttls()
smtp0bj.login('example@gmail.com',password)
smtp0bj.sendmail('example@gmail.com','example2@gmail.com','example3@hotmail.com','subject:Testmail\nTesting,testing,1,2,3,testing'
{}
smtp0bj.quit()
```

According to my textbook, *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* by Al Sweigart, I'm right, but I keep getting an error message. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or have I missed a vital step?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific than just "I keep getting an error message".  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact error
text  (preferably using copy+paste to avoid
transcription errors).

Answer (score 4):

One of your problems seems to be a syntax error at the start of the program: when you ask for the password input, you open two sets of brackets `input(str(`, then only close one set, so adding an extra close-brackets to the end should fix that problem.

You could however, replace the `input(str("text"))` with just `input("text")` as what you are trying to do there is convert a string into a string, which is just a waste of time, what you may be trying to do, however is get the input as a string (`str(input("text"))`), which is needless in this case, as inputs are automatically read as strings in python.

It also seems that you are not defining `smtp0bj`, I'm not sure where you got the name from, so perhaps another read of the textbook (I'm assuming the name came from the textbook) would reveal a missing line or two.

In case your code doesn't work out, here is a copy of a program that I use to send emails in Gmail through python:

```
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
import logging, logging.handlers, sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

try:
    logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    to=""                       #Recipient's email address
    frm=""                      #Sender's email address
    pswd=""                     #Sender's password
    sub=""                      #Subject of email
    text=""                     #Message to send
    msg = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    msg['Subject'] = sub
    msg['To'] = to
except Exception as err:
    pass

try:
    conn = SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
    conn.set_debuglevel(True)
    conn.login(frm, pswd)
    try: conn.sendmail(frm, to, msg.as_string())
    finally: conn.close()
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    logger.error("ERROR!!!")
    logger.critical(exc)
    sys.exit("Mail failed: {}".format(exc))
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

I found your book online (https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/) and found that you have missed a step, defining the smtp server. Adding in the line `smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)` will allow you to send emails from Gmail.

```
import smtplib
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('MyEmailAddress@gmail.com', 'MyEmailPassword')
smtpObj.sendmail('MyEmailAddress@gmail.com', 'RecipientEmailAddress@example.com', 'Subject: SubjectText.\nMessage Text')
smtpObj.quit()
```

Also: Make sure that your program is not called `email.py` as tht is the name of one of the modules used in stmplib, so it will raise an `AtributeError`.